# how to set width and height of a UIVIew in pixels?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, pixel, scaling

I am working on an ObjectiveC app in which I need to set the width and height of a uiview in pixels and than scale that uiview equal to the devices width. The width and height values in pixels are fixed ( let say 900 px x 500 px).

Currently I am doing this,

```
    UIScreen* mainScreen = [UIScreen mainScreen];

    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 900.0, 500.0);
    [view setFrame:frame];
    CGFloat valScale = mainScreen.bounds.size.width/900.0;
    [view setContentScaleFactor:valScale];
```

But this is not giving me the desired values.

What should I do?

(P.S) Does `view.frame.size.width` return the width in pixels or points?

Comment: It gives point. And `pixel = points x2`.

Comment: Why don't you use AutoLayout?

Comment: @trungduc how can i set width and height of uiview in pixels by using autolayouts??

Comment: @k_dev For your question, `NSLayoutDimension` class and `constraintEqualToConstant:` method can help you do it. I saw you mentioned in below answer that you want to scale the view equal to the devices width so why don't you simply set view's width equal to screen width?

Comment: One more thing maybe you didn't know. On iPad, they have split mode and while app is in this mode, the window's width is not equal to screen width.

Comment: width and height of uiview in pixels is fixed (i.e 900px x 500px). but if let say device has screen width equal to 800 pixels and my view has width equal to 900 pixel. In this case the view should be scaled down equal to device's width. Same as in case of higher device's width (for eg, device screen width is 1000 pixel and view is of 900 pixels than in this case uiview should be scaled up equal to device's width). I hope you get this now

Comment: @k_dev I still don't understand why you have to scale the view to make it have full screen width instead of using AutoLayout. Maybe you can explain why its width and height is fixed?

Comment: as i said, i dont want to change uiview width and height, they are FIXED. just want to scale the uiview to devices width

Comment: @k_dev - are you working with an **image** (in a `UIImageView`)? If so, setting the Content Mode of the image view will handle the scaling. If you're working with a `UIView`, there really is no such thing as "pixels" in the way you are describing trying to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Hi for scaling a view you can use the transform property. Say you wish to scale your UIView by a factor of 2 then you can use.

```
self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 2, 2);
```

CGRect width and height returns points not pixels. One point has two pixels for 2x devices like iPhone 6,7 and three pixels for 3x devices like iPhone 6 Plus,7 Plus.

For more detail you can refer [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/Displays/Displays.html) Apple's documentation link.

Comment: thanks for the quick response. i want to scale the view equal to the devices  width. i dont know will it be 2 factor scaling or not. it will be decided on run time whether the view needs to be scaled up or scaled down as user can use ipads. whichever the device would be, just the view should be equal to device's width.